# Как правильно работать с многомерным массивом?

Tags: php, json

Есть массив

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                   [category_name] => Кофе
    [ingredients] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [structure_id] => 52
                                 )
     [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [structure_id] => 52
                                 )
     [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [structure_id] => 52
                                 )
     [...] => Array
                                (
                                    [structure_id] => 52
                                 )
```

Как мне обработать ingredients?

Делал так

```
foreach ($response['response'] as $value) {
    foreach($response['ingredients'] as $val){
        $ingredient_name = $val['ingredient_name'];
 echo $ingredient_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($response['response'] as $value) {
foreach($value['ingredients'] as $val){
    $ingredient_name = $val['ingredient_name'];
    echo $ingredient_name;
}
```